# How can I disable live reload in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I would like to turn off the automatic app refresh in meteor that occurs every time I change a file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable HCP (hot code push) by adding this anywhere in your client code:

```js
Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function() {
  return [false];
});
```

After doing that, you'll need to manually refresh the page in order to see any new changes.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for only one template?

Comment: Just a heads up - `Meteor._reload` is deprecated, and has been removed as of Meteor 1.6.1. `Reload._onMigrate` can be used instead.

Answer (score 19):

You can start your app with the `--once` flag, like so: `meteor --once`.

Comment: can you give further details of what this command exactly does?

Comment: can you give a link where did you find `--once` flag?

Comment: This won't reload the code when you reload the page, though.

Answer (score 4):

Building on those David's response, here's how I've been doing it to let components stop hot code push while they are alive:

```
let shouldReloadPage = false;
const componentsBlockingHCP = [];

Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function() {
  if (componentsBlockingHCP.length) { 
    shouldReloadPage = true;
    return [false];
  }
  shouldReloadPage = false;
  return [true];
});

/*
 * Prevent hot push
 */
export const delayHCP = (component) => {
  if (componentsBlockingHCP.indexOf(component) < 0)
    componentsBlockingHCP.push(component);
};

/*
 * Enable, and reload if hot pushed has been requested when it was not available
 */
export const stopHCPDelay = (component) => {
  const idx = componentsBlockingHCP.indexOf(component);
  if (idx !== -1)
    componentsBlockingHCP.splice(idx, 1);

  if (shouldReloadPage && !componentsBlockingHCP.length) {
    location.reload();
  }
};
```

And then, from a component (with React syntax):

```
componentDidMount() {
  delayHCP(this);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  stopHCPDelay(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small trick for that. Put `#` in the end of the url of the page you are working and press `Enter`, then continue to work on your code. Once you save the file, page will not be refreshed till you refresh it manually (`F5` or `cmd + R`) This way will prevent the page to refresh, but the new code is still pushed to the client and you don't need to disable the HCP for the whole site. Disadvantage: you don't know when the new code is pushed to the client