# Meteor and VSCode: Rebuild after unsaved changes

Tags: meteor, visual-studio-code

here's something that has been bugging me for some time: 
On a Linux system (Linux Mint) I am developing a Meteor application with VSCode. And it's working quite well. I find the integrated terminal very useful. But here's where the problem starts:
In the terminal I can see, when Meteor (just executed with `meteor`) is rebuilding and restarting. And here I spotted, that Meteor is actually rebuilding every time I change something in a file. And not just when it's saved: When I have the Meteor server running, open up a source code file and type `asd` anywhere in the code (and without saving the edited file), the Meteor server almost immediately rebuilds and shows, that the syntax is incorrect. This is bugging me, because when writing code, the server constantly tries to rebuild and shows error messages, simply because I am not done writing yet.
Unfortunately, I am not sure where to start investigating this. I think it might be an issue with VSCode creating files somewhere so unsaved changes are not lost. I have, however, already tried disabling "Hot Exit" in VSCode, of course without success."files.autoSave" is turned off, so it really is trying to compile unsaved changes, not just auto saving them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable live reload in meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682888/how-can-i-disable-live-reload-in-meteor)

Comment: If Meteor's live reload hasn't changed, it is not the same. I do want it to rebuild and reload when I save the file but not while I am writing and editing the file without saving...

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Try a different IDE to confirm it's only VS Code causing the behaviour.
2. Use inotify to check whether any files in your Meteor directory are being modified: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify.
3. inotify should also confirm that auto save is definitely not working.